# Summation without + operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Need to get sum of x and y without `+` operator.

I trid to sum two number using adder.If we xor x and y (`x ^ y`) , we will get summation without carry. From `x & y` we can get carry. To add this carry in summation , call add function again. but its not give answer. where is the error in my code.

```
def add(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return add(a^b, a&b)

x = 10
y = 20
print(add(10, 20))
```

**Error:**

> File "main.py", line 4, in add
>
> ```
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 4, in add                                        
>
> return add(a^b, a&b)                                                                                                                          File "main.py", line 2, in add                                        
>
> if a == 0:                                                                                                                                  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
> ```

Comment: What about `add = int.__add__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have to shift the carries:

```
def add(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return add(a^b, (a&b) << 1)

x = 3
y = 2
print(add(x, y))
# 5
```

Comment: Well, I liked it too when I saw it. I was more lazy than elegant... ;)

Comment: I was lazy - I just tested it with 10,20 and 11,20 because dropping the carry seemed funny - should have tried some more or read it up.

Comment: Yep, 10 and 20 was just bad luck - I even did it by hand afterward to see how it managed to give the right answer anyway!  A nice problem now would be to generate test cases that succeed with the wrong algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

This explains **only** why you end in an endless loop. Your proposed addition algorithm is flawed, see [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849067/7505395)'s answer for a correct addition as well.

---

You forgot half of the base case:

```
def add(a,b):
    if a == 0 or b==0:   # if either one is zero
        return a or b         # return the non-zero one (or 0 if both are 0)
    return add(a^b, a&b)

x = 10
y = 20
print(add(10, 20))
```

prints

```
30     # this only works for some numbers, you algo is not correct, try add(3,2)
```

---

Debugging:

```
def add(a,b):
    print(f"a  {bin(a):>10}")
    print(f"b  {bin(b):>10}")
    if a == 0 or b==0:
        return a or b
    return add(a^b, a&b)

a      0b1010
b     0b10100
-------------        # manually added the xor/and
xor     11110        # to show what happens:
and     00000        # b is 0       

a     0b11110
b         0b0        # now it terminates as b is 0
```

Comment: @Asha see the edit - I added some output and the binary calculations

Answer (score 0):

You missed two condition. If b == 0 then return a. Then also shift carry.

```
def add(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return add(a^b, a&b << 1)

x = 10
y = 20
print(add(10, 20))
```